# I want to remove \\n and other symbols from a string in R

Tags: r, regex, string

I am trying to remove all the special symbols from my string to keep words only

using the below code :

```
nont <- c("\n", "\t", "\r","\"")
x <- gsub(paste(nont,collapse="|"), " ", x)
```

still not able to get rid of multiple spaces or multiple new lines 
sample from my output :
as\nsuccessful integrations on a variety of microcontrollers.  ,

i also applied this : "[^[:alnum:] ]"
but its removing \ symbol without the letter n for (double newline \n)

Comment: what "special symbols" could be present in your environment, are they only those you provided? You know, the unicode plains is immense big.

Comment: mainly  \\n , single and double quotes